# Python Flask - cannot use custom domain names

Tags: python, flask

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subdomain-in-flask-python/) describing how to use alternate domain names with Flask (anything other than localhost). However, I'm getting a "Name or service not known" error when attempting to use **flask.dev**.

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

# Set the domain name
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'flask.dev:5000'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Modified the hosts file (in /etc/hosts) and restarted system:**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       flask.dev
```

(Pinging both localhost and flask.dev above works.)

**Error message when using flask.dev:**

```
integration@example:~$ python app.py
 * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./app.py", line 241, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 922, in run
    run_simple(t.cast(str, host), port, self, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 982, in run_simple
    s.bind(server_address)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

**No error message when using localhost:**

Oddly enough it works if I change `app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'flask.dev:5000'` to `app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'localhost:5000'` in app.py.

```
integration@example:~$ python app.py
 * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://localhost:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 144-957-730
```

What needs to be done to resolve this issue?

Comment: it works for me on Linux Mint 20 (based on Ubuntu 20.04) and I don't have to restart computer after changing `/etc/hosts`. Did you check if you still have `flask.dev` in `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: but this gives me other problem - web browser automatically converts me `http://flask.dev:5000` to `https` and `flask` can't respond. Using ie. `flask.local` I don't have this problem.

Comment: @furas I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. I checked, `flask.dev` is in `/etc/hosts` but still getting `socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`

Comment: check other values `hosts` like `127.0.0.1    flask.local` or even `127.0.0.1  flask`. Maybe older Ubuntu worked in different way. Maybe it had other file for this. You can also check in terminal if system can recognize it `ping flask.dev`

Comment: last idea - check in Google `ubuntu 18.04 hosts file not working` to see if someone else had the same problem

Comment: Note: .dev is an actual TLD and: [Chrome & Firefox now force .dev domains to HTTPS via preloaded HSTS](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/)